# What are difference between Computer Vision API v1.0 and v2.0?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Both have their own documentation and I see only small wording differences between those. Are there list of things that have actually changed? Has OCR for example improved on version 2.0 or it's the same except I guess the handwriting recognition? Some kind of changelog would really make a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference between v1.0 and v2.0 is the revised `/recognizedText` which has a breaking change in the input/output.  All other endpoints are exactly the same.  Also, if you have an key in an up-to-date pricing tier (including free), your API key will work in both versions.

As you may know, the Computer Vision API has two different OCR endpoints.  The `/ocr` endpoint runs the older recognition engine with broader language coverage.  The newer `/recognizeText` endpoint, which in v1.0 handled handwritten text, in v2.0 covers both handwritten and printed text using a newer engine.  The `/recognizeText` endpoint remains English-only for now.  You select between handwritten/printed modalities using the `mode` query parameter. See 
 documentation [here](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5adf991815e1060e6355ad44/operations/587f2c6a154055056008f200).

As for documenting changes, there isn't one obvious place for this unfortunately.  One option is to check the swagger [repo](https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/commits/master/specification/cognitiveservices/data-plane/ComputerVision/stable/v2.0/ComputerVision.json).